# Command line argument No such file or directory error in bash

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-arguments

I have written a bash script and when it is executed as

```
./script a b c
```

it is working fine.
then I moved the script to the bin folder and tried to execute it as

```
script a b c
```

now it is showing error

```
a: No such file or directory
b: No such file or directory
c: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: yes it was there.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your script. I suppose program `script` is installed on your system.

See from your bash: `man script`

Comment: the script name was not script. it was ssh-add.There was no binary ssh-add installed in my system.The error was not with that

Comment: Post output of `file $(which ssh-add)`.

Comment: ok . there was an ssh-add already installed.I renamed my script.Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You execute your script with file as a parameter. When you execute by using

```
$ ./script a b c
```

parameter file and script are same location. after moving the file bin folder may be execute script from different location where your parameter file not there.

So execute your script with location of file

```
$ script /path/of/a /path/of/b /path/of/c
```

then it will be worked fine.